# Install self signed Certificates via ADB

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to install self-signed Certificates(created by Charles) via ADB
I've pushed it to /sdcard/xxx.pem , And then failed to open it with Browsers that I could find, And Since the device removes the Setting Application, I could not install cert under the Setting App.
Then I searched And try

```
am start -n com.android.certinstaller/.CertInstallerMain -a android.intent.action.VIEW -t application/x-x509-ca-cert file:///sdcard/test.cer
```

But just shown

```
01-07 17:47:56.442 12889-12889/com.android.certinstaller E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.certinstaller, PID: 12889
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.certinstaller/com.android.certinstaller.CertInstallerMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5418)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:731)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
    at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:60)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:645)
    at com.android.certinstaller.CertInstallerMain.startInstallActivity(CertInstallerMain.java:139)
    at com.android.certinstaller.CertInstallerMain.onCreate(CertInstallerMain.java:119)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5418) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

I'm not familiar with this com.android.certinstaller app, Is there any reference How I could use it to install a cert?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

adb shell am start -n com.android.certinstaller/.CertInstallerMain -a android.intent.action.VIEW -t application/x-x509-ca-cert -d file:///sdcard/test.cer

if throw
com.android.certinstaller E/CertInstaller: Failed to read certificate: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/cer (Permission denied)

please root your devices and push cer to  /system/etc/
adb shell am start -n com.android.certinstaller/.CertInstallerMain -a android.intent.action.VIEW -t application/x-x509-ca-cert -d file:///system/etc/test.cer

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the file is readable if you are getting "Permission denied" or "Cloud not find the file" toast.

`chmod o+r /sdcard/test.cer`

and then

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.certinstaller/.CertInstallerMain -a android.intent.action.VIEW -t application/x-x509-ca-cert -d file:///sdcard/test.cer
```